# How to apply bitwise formula to a range using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a way to apply a bitwise AND on a value in excel and apply it on range. Here is a picture to illustrate :

[image: Exemple picture]

I want to apply a bitwise AND on the Column "Status" with a fixed value, lets say (1001b). 
If  Status & 1001b  = 1001b, then report the "Value" field in "Output". Else, put 0.

Both Excel and VBA can be used, but as the table can be huge, the solution may not use loops (Too slow, time efficient solution would be great). I am using excel 2010, and therefore the excel BITAND function is not available for me (only available since Excel 2013 version)

I search on SO and internet and didn't find a correct approach to a similar problem.
I try to optimize my initial solution which use recursivity, to be more time efficient, here is what I have done :

```
For cptDonnee_s32 = 0 To JeuDonnee_rs.RecordCount - 2 ' Loop through all my data

    If (Value And 8) = 8) And (Value And 1) = 1) Then ' Compare bitfields one by one
        Output = Value ' Replace output by value here
    Else 
        Output  = 0  ' put 0 in output there
    End If
next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple UDF:

```
Function BitAnd(dIn As Double, lMatch As Long) As Boolean
    BitAnd = (dIn And lMatch) = lMatch
End Function
```

and enter:

```
=if(BitAnd(K2,9),L2,0)
```

and copy down.

Comment: Great ! Your solution is very simple and works well ! I had to replace "," by ";" to get a valid formula, but the result is here.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: That's due to your regional settings. :)